# "Calling standalone.conf.bat" when running WildFly 8 standalone.bat

Tags: java, jboss, environment-variables, windows-8.1, wildfly-8

I'm using Windows 8.1 and the WildFly is 8.2. (even though the folder indicates that it is 8.1 I've updated it with a patch by JBoss to 8.2)

I have a project which worked fine a month ago and absolutely no changes have been made to it during this time. Now when I try to run standalone.bat I just get the "Calling standalone.conf.bat" and it stops here.

I found some questions and topics on this and they were solved by setting the environment variables JAVA_HOME and JBOSS_HOME (probably needless) but I do have those variables set as the following image shows.

Here's the first two items of my "path" variable in system environment variables:

One other project required me to change my java to Java 7 and I did and now I changed it back to Java 8 and I get the following problem:

Here's a picture of my command line:

[image]

What other reasons might there be for this behaviour? standalone.xml or ANY other file in the project was not changed in any way since this worked fine so it must be somewhere in the environment variables and java versions.

EDIT: Could it be that the Java version is too new for WildFly 8.2?

I'll try with older Java 7 for example.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is maybe by patching the server, possibly there was a change between 8.1 and 8.2 that your standalone.conf doesnt include?  There's nothing whatsoever in server.log or boot.log?

Comment: Nope. Nothing in the logs since last month. Anyway, I solved this by downloading wildfly 8.2 again and just moving my standalone.xml and jdbc driver with the needed folders to that new wildfly instance and everything works again and the reason remains a mystery.

Comment: Glad you got it working!  Strange though.